# How to debug a NullPointerException on a boolean with Google Maps android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am getting this error on the first time my app loads and requests the user for location permission.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
```

I have an "EntryActivity" and when an enter button is pressed the next activity loaded with an intent is the map activity.

On the first time going from Entry -> Map the app crashes and then just after crashing it asks for user location permission and even though the app has crashed I can still respond "yes" in the location permission dialog and then on all subsequent uses of the app it works fine and doesn't crash.

The problem is probably with mLocationPermissionGranted. Does that need to be set first to a value eg. false?

To setup the use of location I used the android dev guide.

In map activity is the following code:

```
Boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;
public final static int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
public final static int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 4;

FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
Location mLastKnownLocation;
private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085);
```

And in onCreate:

```
mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

And in onMapReady:

```
    getLocationPermission();

    updateLocationUI();

    getDeviceLocation();
```

And the implementation of these methods are exactly as per the Android docs (except there is the line   mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult(); but I just had to cast to   mLastKnownLocation = (Location) task.getResult();)

If anyone sees anything glaringly obvious that'd be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
> ```

The exception comes from trying to unbox a `Boolean` that is null.

> The problem is probably with mLocationPermissionGranted. Does that need to be set first to a value eg. false?

Likely, since that is the only `Boolean` type in the code you posted. Your options include:

1. Change it to primitive `boolean` (note lowercase `b`)
2. Init it with a value such as `Boolean.FALSE`.
3. Check for nullity before unboxing, e.g. `mLocationPermissionGranted != null && mLocationPermissionGranted`.

Comment: Cool. That's fixed. But now from within the  private void getDeviceLocation() method i'm getting a null exception with  new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude() - and that makes sense because on the first time the app launches there is no LastKnownLocation - but these methods are taken from the android docs and I would have thought that would have been taken into account. And I didn't want to just hard code the last known location. Advice would be cool. Thx.

Comment: And does it matter if i'm debugging with an emulator or device?